# When is RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[...]] faster than (N)Integrate[Boole[...]]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, regions

I wanted to use Mathematica to compute areas and volumes of various implicitly defined regions, so I ran a simple test case using the unit circle:

```
Integrate[Boole[x^2 + y^2 <= 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.10, π} *)

RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00735, π} *)
```

To my surprise, `RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[...]]` is more than 10 times faster than `Integrate[Boole[..]]` on this problem. `NIntegrate` is only slightly slower than `RegionMeasure`, but does not return a symbolic result.

---

On the other hand, on the areas I want to compute,

```
lerp[t_, a_, b_] := (1 - t) a + t b
f[f00_, f01_, f10_, f11_][x_, y_] := 
 Evaluate@Expand@lerp[x, lerp[y, f00, f01], lerp[y, f10, f11]]
areaNIntegrate[f00_, f01_, f10_, f11_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Boole[f[f00, f01, f10, f11][x, y] >= 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
areaRegionMeasure[f00_, f01_, f10_, f11_] := 
 RegionMeasure@
  ImplicitRegion[
   f[f00, f01, f10, f11][x, y] >= 0, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}]
```

`NIntegrate` is usually faster, sometimes by a lot:

```
timings = 
  Table[{areaNIntegrate @@ # // Timing // First, 
      areaRegionMeasure @@ # // Timing // First} &@
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4], 1000];
Show[ListPlot[timings, AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 0.020}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thin, Dashed}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

(*x*-axis: `NIntegrate` time, *y*-axis: `RegionMeasure` time on same data)

---

Is this expected? Why is there such a difference? Practically, is there some rule of thumb to know which of (`N`)`Integrate[Boole[...]]` and `RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[...]]` is better, or must we always test the performance of both?

Answer (score 3):

The ones for which `NIntegrate` is really fast are empty regions.

```
SeedRandom[0];
Flatten@Table[
  If[1.6 ((foo = areaNIntegrate @@ #) // AbsoluteTiming // First) < 
        (areaRegionMeasure @@ # // AbsoluteTiming // First),
      foo, {}] &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4], 1000]
(*
  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}
*)
```

As for the rest, a pattern eludes me.